# Apache redirect from https

Tags: linux, apache

I installed an SSL Certificate on my server, and https works fine.

Http redirect works fine for example `http://login.example.com` -> `https://example1.com/index.html`

But redirect from https not working, for example `https://login.example.com` -> `https://example1.com/index.html`.

its just go to the main page of my server `https://redirect.example.com`

Any suggestions on how to get the redirect from https to work?

Thanks !

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    ServerName redirect.example.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^login\.example\.com(.*)
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example1.com/index.html [L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/httpd/my.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/my.pem
    ServerName redirect.mydomain.com

    RewriteEngine On
    ServerName redirect.example.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^login\.example\.com(.*)
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example1.com/index.html [L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks!

Comment: i will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use server alias for your Rewrite Rule:

```
ServerAlias login.example.com
```

you can use multiple `ServerAlias` for multiple `Rewrite Rule`

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have a duplicate ServerName directive in your SSL host declaration.
That could be causing trouble.

From the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername):

> If you are using name-based virtual hosts, the ServerName inside a  section specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to match this virtual host.

Comment: thanks, I tried to remove the servername on https but it doesnt work

Comment: If you're expecting visitors to come from login.example.com, then this is what you should use as ServerName instead of redirect.mydomain.com. Then restart Apache

Comment: what do you mean with use as ServerName instead of redirect.mydomain.com?

Comment: the server name is like http `ServerName redirect.example.com` and its works, im not sure what do you mean with your answer, what should I do different?

Comment: Assuming your URL is `https://login.example.com`, you just put this line in your SSL host declaration: `ServerName login.example.com`. It should match the actual domain name.

Comment: but if I have multiple rules under ssl, why I cant do it like http? 
also when I tried your soultion it redirect to  
`www.exaple1.com/https://example1.com/index.html`

Comment: I need solution for multiple rules, should work like http

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by multiple rules ? Multiple domain names/subdomains ?

A plain redirect of http(s)://login.example.com to https://example1.com/index.html should be achieved this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName login.example.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^login\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://example1.com/index.html [L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/httpd/my.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/my.pem
ServerName login.example.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^login\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://example1.com/index.html [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Important: ServerName should match your SSL certificate's Common Name (unless it's a wildcard certificate).

NB: RewriteEngine may be overkill for your purpose since the Apache mod_alias module provides the Redirect directive which may be sufficient here.
From the Apache documentation: [When not to use mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/avoid.html)